# I can't use custom code in infopath but I got the tools

Tags: infopath

I have sharepoint server, vs2013 and when I try to enter code in an infopath form with the "on load event" button of the form in the section developer it gives me a "missing programmability components", but I have used my vs2013 and it allows me to create webparts, event receivers, etc. the error code is below:

missing programmability components
the following external components are required ....

microsoft vs 2012
visual studio c# support
microsoft visual studio tools for applications 2012 (DOWNLOAD)

continues....

I downloaded the tools and installed, then when trying to create the code it says that visual studio tools needs repair vs, so I went to programs-change and then you got the option to repair vs.

the repair fails saying that I need  the .net framework 4.5.1 for Asia, but my computer is spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Visual Studio Tools for Applications it is installed with the Office package or InfoPath which ever you have installed. There you can edit the code.

Here is what Microsoft has to say:

*Visual Studio 2013 does not include the InfoPath form template projects that were provided in previous versions of Visual Studio. You also cannot use Visual Studio 2013 to open or edit an InfoPath form template project that was created in a previous version of Visual Studio. However, you can open and edit an InfoPath form template project by using Visual Studio Tools for Applications. For more information, see Working with VSTO 2008 Projects in InfoPath 2010.*

Here is the source link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772074.aspx

Edit:
If you have Visual Studio 2012 you can also use that but you need on of the following Supported Microsoft Visual Studio version:Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Premium or Professional
To use the Tools for applications plugin for VS2012

Comment: I don't understand your answer, my problem is that vsta was not installed and if I try to install it gives me problems.

Comment: You are trying to use the VSTA together with Visual Studio 2013 right? if that is the case then it is not supported. You need to have VS2012 Ultimate, Premium or Professional. If i misunderstood please try to clarify.

Comment: Now is so clear, I will try to install vs 2012. thanks.